# Replacing elements of variable in Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I replace every element in the variable data that is less than 0.5 with 0.

I tried this, but it's not working.

```
rng(110)
data= rand(1, 1e8);
tstart = tic;
count = (data<0.5);
replace = replacedata(data,count,0);
telapsed = toc(tstart);
```

Answer (score 2):

what is `replacedata`?? This is quite basic matlab using logical indexing like so:

```
data(data < 0.5) = 0
```

Or alternatively:

```
replace = data.*(data < 0.5)  %// This only works because you are replacing the value with 0 as Matlab automatically casts logical matrices to doubles when using arithmetic.
```

Answer (score 2):

The method [`replacedata`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/dataset.replacedata.html) is for [`dataset`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/dataset-class.html) variables. Your `data` matrix is a standard Matlab matrix created using [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/rand.html). Therefore the `replacedata` function can't be used with it.

It is possible to create a `dataset` type variable from your matrix using [`mat2dataset`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/mat2dataset.html), but as Dan explained in his answer, it is simpler to use logical indexing.